# Adjust top margin in layout file depending on Navbar height

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, layout

I have an ASP MVC Application and in the layout view file I added an image (400px x 400px).
I set the class to img-respsonsive and added some padding to the image.

I want to div that contains the `@RenderBody()` method to automatically adjust the `margin-top` style so it moves down depending on the height of the navbar header.

I use maax-width of %20 percent(80px) and I set the margin-top to the max value which works.  But I would like to not have so much whitespace if possible.

How can I do this?

Here is the source code:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img class="img-circle" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/IdeaConTempLogo.png")" style="max-width: 20%; padding: 9px 15px 8px;"/>
            @Html.ActionLink("Brand", "Home", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- TODO: Adjust the top margin to automatically to add space depending on navbar height -->
<div class="container body-content" style="margin-top:80px">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - IdeaCon All Rights Reserved</p>
        <p></p>
    </footer>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check height on document ready function by this:

```
var heightSlider = $('.navbar').height();
```

Then apply the same for margin-top, like so:

```
$('.body-content').css({ marginTop : heightSlider + 30 + 'px' });
```

Hope that helps